# Stage does not show up on the screen with viewport

Tags: libgdx, viewport, stage

I have one stage that is initialised in the following way:

```
final Viewport viewport = game.getCamera().viewport;
final SpriteBatch sb = Rosjam.get().getSb();
this.stage = new Stage(viewport, sb);
```

The camera is initialised with this code:

```
this.camera = new Camera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
float w = 21f;
float h = 11f;
this.camera.viewport = new FitViewport(w, h, camera);
this.camera.viewport.apply();
```

I have one actor added to the scene (a touchpad actor). If I remove all the code from the viewport and initialise the stage with an empty constructor (without using the camera viewport), the stage is rendered as expected but if I use the viewport the touchpad is not rendered.

I also tried to resize or override the resize method to resize the viewport. I think the problem comes from the viewport. The stage has been set to use debug mode, so I can see the bounds. Although the bounds are fine the touchpad does not show it.

Any idea what is going on or how to solve this problem?

Comment: Very hard to tell what's going on in your code with so little context when you are using multiple types of classes named Camera or instances named `camera`.

Comment: the problem was that you need to initialise the stage with a new camera, not with the camera used for the game.  You can use your own SpriteBatch renderer for the stage